# Google Chrome Extensions - Not Searchable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My first chrome extension worked fine when first made, I could search for it on Google or the Chrome App Store and it would be first or second. About a week ago it completely disappeared from Google searches, now the only thing i can find when searching for it in google is the report abuse page. Convenient right?  Here is the [link to that extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adidas-stock-checker/nemkgpphahnmkehhcfodojikdecdgoch).

I wasn't really bothered by this issue until I created my next extension, which was paid this time. Right from get-go after publishing It wouldn't appear in any chrome store searches or google searches. The only way to get it was to click a direct link. Convenient right? Here is the [link to that extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simply-fill-for-supreme/noejjajllnpkeddahmlnbkmmoiekpiem).

If anyone has any tips please let me know. Or if there are any Chrome staff out there, please help me out :}.

Answer (score 0):

It shows up first for me. Maybe it is just that account/computer.

Try searching it on a public or not-yours computer to see.

---

[image]

Comment: For that one it only "completely disappeared from Google searches".